# Test client availability in WCF wsDualHttpBinding callback with Remote Address

Tags: c#, wcf, callback, wsdualhttpbinding

So there is this issue with making sure the client is still available when doing a callback in WCF when using WSDualHttpBinding. Polling is an expensive and unreliable solution. It occurred to me that maybe a simple HTTP POST or GET to the clients address (OperationContext.Current.Channel.RemoteAddress) would at least tell you if the client was there. You'd still probably get a 400, bad request error, but so long as it wasn't a 404 or 503, you could probably assume that the client was still there. This still seems a bit kludgy, so I was wondering if anyone had any other ideas or could point out a serious flaw in the logic of checking the RemoteAddress before making the callback.